# What does '|| {}' together mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I met some syntax, which is not clear for me, like this:

```
anotherVariable = anotherVariable || {};
var variable = anotherVariable.member = anotherVariable.member || {};
```

What does the code above mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default value setter.

```
anotherVariable = anotherVariable || {};
```

if `anotherVariable`  is `falsy` then it'll set `{}` in `anotherVariable`.

`''` , `null`, `0` ,`undefined`,`NaN` consider `falsy` in javascript.

This is same for

```
var variable = anotherVariable.member = anotherVariable.member || {};
```

if `anotherVariable.member` is `falsy` then `{}` will be set in `anotherVariable.member` and then `anotherVariable.member` will be set in `variable`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a combination of few things

1. Any not null object in js is `true` in all comparisons
2. `{}` is a definition of empty object
3. So it means this:

   `if (anotherVariable != null)
   {
      anotherVariable  = {};
   }`

Answer (score 0):

anotherVariable become an empty hash/opbject {} if it is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple :

```
var a = b || {};
```

set variable "a" to "b". If b is null or undefined, set "a" to `{}`

```
var variable = anotherVariable.member = anotherVariable.member || {};
```

set `anotherVariable.member` to `{}` if it's null or undefined.
then set `variable` to `anotherVariable.member`